# Build chart inside all items inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to use [Easy Pie Chart plugin](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/) inside a ng-repeat. But how can I call the chart constructor (JS) when all items is rendered?

```
<a ng-repeat="meta in metas.metas.lista" class="item item-avatar" style="padding-left: 16px;top:45px;">                
   <!-- Chart here -->
   <div class="chart" data-percent="{{meta.score.ScoreMeta | number:0}}">{{meta.score.ScoreMeta | number:0}}</div>
</a>
```

To build the chart, I need the following JS code

```
$('.chart').easyPieChart();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS does not work that way. I would suggest you write an angular directive and within its link function you will be able to access the element and apply easyPieChart() to it.

```
angular.module('whatever-app-it-is')
.directive('chart', function() {
  return {
     restrict: 'C',
     link: function(elem, attr) {
       jQuery(elem).easyPieChart();
     }
  }
})
```

Comment: when jQuery.js is included before angular.js `elem` is already a jQuery object, no need to wrap it in `$()` again,